# Android Camera preview that lights up with the change of a threshold (moving object)

Tags: eclipse, camera, adt, preview, rect

I'm trying to develop an app for Android with ADT and I'm stuck on the preview of the camera.

My app should try to recognize into camera preview the passage of an object within a rectangle, drawn on the preview of the camera.
The movement of the object  must light up the rectangle.

I developed my preview for now and draw the rectangle.
My idea involves two steps:

1. make only a preview tones in gray
2. To illuminate the rectangle to change the threshold of gray within the rectangle.

What do you recommend?

This follows the full code:

```
public class CameraTestActivity extends Activity {
CameraPreview cv;
DrawView dv;
FrameLayout bingo;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

public void Load(){

    Camera c = getCameraInstance();


    if (c != null){

        bingo = new FrameLayout(this);
        bingo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        cv = new CameraPreview(this,c);
        bingo.addView(cv);

        dv = new DrawView(this);
        bingo.addView(dv);

        setContentView(bingo);
    }
    else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "Unable to find camera. Closing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        finish();
    }
}


public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;

    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c; 
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (cv != null){
        cv.onPause();
        cv = null;
    }
}


@Override 
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    Load();
}

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CameraView", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      return;
    }

    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }


    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("CameraView", "Error" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}
}

public class DrawView extends SurfaceView{


public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);



    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){


    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle (Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawRect((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (canvas.getWidth() / 6),
            (canvas.getHeight() / 2) - (canvas.getHeight() / 14) ,
            (canvas.getWidth() / 2) + (canvas.getWidth() / 6),
            (canvas.getHeight() / 2) + (canvas.getHeight() / 14), paint);

}
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't draw anything about your object. I wrote a simple app for face detection before. I created a relativeLayout, a surfaceView for camera preview, and a custom view for drawing face rectangle. I think it's similar to yours. Just draw the object rectangle in `onDraw`.

Comment: My request was for advice on how to recognize a moving object within the box and make it sensitive the rect to the movement of the object. Makes sense to use sensor listener?

Comment: there's no Android API for moving object detection. You can try OpenCV or other image processing libraries, which can analyze the successive frames and find out the moving object.

Comment: thanks! :( I was hoping to play on the variation of threshold color... it is impossible in any case?